# How to set punctuation in Yii2 form text field?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2, kartik-v

I've a form in my Yii2 application. I'm using Kartik\form\activeFor.
This is a little view of my form
[image]

And this is the code

```
'jumlahBruto' => ['type' => Form::INPUT_TEXT, 'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Nilai Total Bruto...'];
```

How do I can set the data in text field has a **dot** like this 
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: add class and use [this](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your code for masking

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#date").mask("99.999.999");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<input id="date" type="text">
```

This will solve your problem.

**EDIT**

As mentioned in documentation, in modal dom is already not loaded.
You need to explicitely call input mask for dynamically loaded elements.

```
$(":input").inputmask(); $(document).on("ajaxComplete", function(e){ 
   $(":input").inputmask(); 
});
```

as per author of inputmask here is the [link](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/issues/782).

Comment: I've no idea how do I can try your suggestion. Because I'm using kartik FormGrid. Just like the code I've showed above. I dont know where I can set the id/class in the form.

Comment: There must be some id you are providing to that element, if not give it an id. and apply maskedinput on that as I applied for element with date id

Comment: It will take automatically, inspect it and then check what will be the element id. You will get it

Comment: I got the way to add ID :D, I'll try your suggestion :)

Comment: Let me know if still facing problem

Comment: try to load js in modal itself and then check, because, in modal, if content is loaded dynamically, then you have to bind it explicitely

Comment: But where exactly I should put the script? the modal form is in _form.php. I've set like this inside `<div class="form> <?php "$scriptOne = 'src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"';
    echo "<script ".$scriptOne.">"."</script>";` but didn't work, and it also didn't show any error message

Comment: try like this, `$(":input").inputmask();
$(document).on("ajaxComplete", function(e){
    $(":input").inputmask();
});` in modal and dont forget to add your own mask and change that :input by your id

Comment: I have add `$("#wp-modal").mask("99.999.999.9-999.999"); $(document).on("ajaxComplete", function(e){ $("#wp-modal").mask("99.999.999.9-999.999"); });` but also didn't work :(

Comment: Actually when I tried to div an id using jquery it's work, but when I try the mask It give me error message **TypeError: $(...).mask is not a function**.

Comment: Add maskinput js in parent file and in modal file add the code I have sent you

Comment: Done! it's work, I've done like your suggestion. Thankyou somuch buddy :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155596/discussion-between-rahul-meshram-and-blackjack).